# Evee not rendering properly

Tags: rendering, export, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to export this video project, but all i see when i export is a grey screen.

I am using Evee and have attached screenshots of all my settings. Hopefully someone can help! I have no other ideas about what i'm doing wrong here.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. i went to the video sequencer and there was a random video file there which i needed to delete. i also checked my compositor window and linked the render layers directly to the composite node and everything started working properly. just in case someone else out there has a similar issue :)